# Jenkins automatic git polling stuck after pulling with a tag or commit

Tags: git, jenkins, branch

I want a build to occur each time a user `commit on any branches` and also manually when I `trigger a specific build` by providing a `commitid` or a `branch name` (ie: refs/tags/TAG_NAME).

Both mode are working fine by using a build parameter and using that variable (cf config part) but when I trigger a build with a specific branch (or commit) the `git polling` is stucked on a specific version and so new commit are ignored.

As a workaround I can trigger manually a build by providing `**` or `origin/master`and then the config is back to normal. But this is painful for users and I'd like to fix this issue…

**Polling output:**

[image: Git polling log normal mode]
[image: Git polling mode stuck on a tag]

**Configuration:**

[image: Build parameter config]
[image: Source code configuration]
[image: Poll SCM config]

**What I tired**

I tried to add a post code to reset the scm state at the end of the job execution, but this not working. Any clue ?

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note: I setup the jenkins config to only build one job at a time (concurrency disabled so I don't have constraint about this).

Answer (score 0):

I found too late that there is a open bug about that: with https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27349

Just found it by looking at the next release log of the gitplugin **Version 2.4.0** (coming -> Jul 18, 2015 - estimated). Hope it will fix the issue.